# Describe basis for following topology

Tags: general-topology

Let R+ $\cup$ {0} be the set of non-negative real numbers and give it the usual metric topology induced by the absolute value metric.

Describe a basis for this topology

I am thinking the British rail metric as a basis

That is my best guess. Any help would
be appreciated.

Comment: A basis is a collection of open sets; why are you mentioning a metric different from the one already given?

Comment: If $\mathfrak B$ is a basis for the topology on $\mathbb R$, then $\{U\cap(\mathbb R_+\cup\{0\}):U\in\mathfrak B\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R_+\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: I went looking on the net to describe it and thought that was it @angryavian

Comment: A metric is not a basis.

Comment: Given a metric on a set, the base for its topology follows. Recall your theory...

Comment: “Thus open intervals generate the topology on the real line”,pg 72 So it can be arbitrary …

Comment: So how can it be arbitrary then? P72 from what?

Comment: A first course in Topology,Conover.  from an arbitrary open set is the union of open intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis will be: $\mathcal B =\{B_{(x,\epsilon)}: x\in \mathbb R^+\cup \{0\}, 0<\epsilon\leq x\}$ with $B_{(x,\epsilon)}=\{y\in \mathbb R^+\cup \{0\}: |x-y|<\epsilon\}$